# How to interpret condition with comparing result of binary operator?

Tags: c++

I have this code:

```
if((bob.prop & 0x100) == 0x100) {
    // some code
}
```

I found that this part:

```
bob.prop & 0x100
```

means

> is bob.prop set to 0x100?

So, I think it gives me true or false. But the result of this code is comparing with 0x100 also:

```
if((bob.prop & 0x100) == 0x100) {
```

What is it? What does it mean?

Comment: `is bob.prop set to 0x100?` would be `bob.prop == 0x100`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`0x100` in binary is `0000000100000000`, which has its 9th bit set.

Doing `bob.prop & 0x100` filters out that 9th bit from `bob.prop`. For example:

```
bob.prop         & 0x100
1010110101110010 & 0000000100000000 gives 0000000100000000
0110110001101011 & 0000000100000000 gives 0000000000000000
```

It does this because it is the bitwise AND of the two operands. That means the result will only have bits set where bits are set in both of the operands.

You are then checking whether the result is equal to `0000000100000000`, which is the same as asking "Was the 9th bit set?"

It is not necessary to perform this final comparison, because any integer value greater than 0 will convert to `true`, while 0 will convert to `false`. You could just write:

```
if(bob.prop & 0x100)
```

Comment: So `0x100` is a 2 bytes, right? we interprete this 2 bytes as 16 bits and do bitwise and. Result of this operation is comparing with another 2 bytes – with `0x100`. Right?

Comment: "You could just write:": only if your goal is obfuscation.  (On the other hand, I tend to test `!= 0`, rather than `== 0x100`.)

Comment: +1. I'd just add that while the `==` is superfluous in this case, it makes a difference once more than one bit is set in the mask (e.g. `0x110`. Then, it's a difference between "all are set" and "any is set".

Comment: @JamesKanze I'd say that in this case, "obfuscation" is subjective - it's clearer to me without the `==`.

Comment: @SharikovVladislav More likely 32 bits.  He just used 16 bits for display purposes, since all of the additional higher order bits would be 0.

Comment: @Angew Not really.  Hidden type conversions are obfuscation, no matter how you look at it, and expressions like `bob.prop & 0x100` are confusing, even to someone with a lot of experience; if you want a `bool`, say so.

Comment: @SharikovVladislav As James said, I only wrote it as 16 bits because I know it will be at least that big but probably bigger. Writing any more preceding 0s is just unnecessary and would make my answer harder to read.

Comment: @JosephMansfield I am trying to help my friend with it. I really don't understand what is `0x100` here (or `0x80`, or `0x40`)? What is it? Representation of something? Where I can read about it? What should I type in google to understand this?

Comment: @SharikovVladislav It's an integer literal in hexadecimal. Do you know how to read hex? The `0x` means "this is hexadecimal", and then the `100` is the value written in hexadecimal.

Comment: @SharikovVladislav `0x80` in binary is `10000000`. `0x40` is `01000000`.

Comment: @Joseph so... there can be any number in hexadecimal from `0x00000000` to `0xFFFFFFFF`. Thats why 32 numbers, right?

Comment: @SharikovVladislav You could have more than that if there is an integer type on your machine that is capable of storing such a value (such as a 64 bit type).

Answer (score 2):

the bob.prop & 0x100 is doing a bitwise and of bob.prop with 0x100. The if statement is ensuring that equals 0x100.

So the first test is evaluating an expression, and putting it in the if checks if it matches 0x100.

Note that you are not testing that bob.prop is set to 0x100, rather than are checking whether one bit is set. So the expression would be true for input of 0x100, 0x101, 0x102, 0xfff, ...